# Find all anchor (<a>) tags that utilize http rather than https?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have recently been experimenting with Google Chrome's console, and the power that it possesses for troubleshooting.

One of the most used snippets I have found myself relying on is `$$(' ')` to search for specific elements, classes, id's, you name it.

I'm wondering if there is a way to use that command to find all anchor tags that hold a url using only `http` or only `https`?

Thanks guys!

Comment: xpath: `//a[starts-with(@href, 'https')]`? Of course, that wouldn't catch protocol-relative `//` uris.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='http:']")`

Comment: @Pointy Thank you! That works wonderfully. I'm curious though, I tried replacing 'document.querySelectorAll' with '$$' and it seemed to work the same way.

To your knowledge (or anyone else reading this), are these both doing the same thing? Is there any situation where you would want to use document.querySelectorAll over $$?

Thanks again for your input. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you're using some sort of framework (or maybe the Chrome console? I don't use Chrome much) then `$$` may be mapped to a function that does essentially the same thing as `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: @DivineChickenwing [They are the same:](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector_1) `This command [i.e., $$] is equivalent to calling document.querySelectorAll().`